# How to run an executable file (.exe) in Windows Powershell with spaces in it?

Tags: c++, powershell, visual-studio-code

Recently I wanted to try out Visual Studio Code for C++ programming. Since I am a fairly new to C++ and programming in general I didn't want to do the tedious setup process for running programs. So I installed the extension "Code Runner" which runs the cpp file in the terminal. It was all going great until I wanted to run cpp files with spaces in them. After some searching I found out that the extension uses some kind of batch file to change the directory of the terminal,compile it and run the output file. When there were spaces in the name the 2 parts of the name were being interpreted as separate commands.This is the `code-runner.executorMap` setting in the VS code settings:

```
"code-runner.executorMap": {
    "javascript": "node",
    "php": "C:\\php\\php.exe",
    "python": "python",
    "perl": "perl",
    "ruby": "C:\\Ruby23-x64\\bin\\ruby.exe",
    "go": "go run",
    "html": "\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe\"",
    "java": "cd $dir && javac $fileName && java $fileNameWithoutExt",
    "c": "cd $dir && gcc $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt"
    "cpp": "cd $dir && g++ $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
    "objective-c": "cd $dir && gcc -framework Cocoa $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt",
```

The output for this was:

```
PS D:\> cd "d:\" ; if ($?) { g++ Test  1.cpp -o Test  1 } ; if ($?) { .\Test  1 }
g++.exe: error: Test: No such file or directory
g++.exe: error: 1.cpp: No such file or directory
g++.exe: error: 1: No such file or directory
```

I managed to fix some of the problem by surrounding the name and directory with double quotes.

```
        "c": "cd $dir && gcc \"$fileName\" -o \"$fileNameWithoutExt\" && \"./$fileNameWithoutExt\"",
        "cpp": "cd $dir && g++ \"$fileName\" -o \"$fileNameWithoutExt\" && \"./$fileNameWithoutExt\"",
        "objective-c": "cd $dir && gcc -framework Cocoa \"$fileName\" -o \"$fileNameWithoutExt\" && \"./$fileNameWithoutExt\"",}
```

The output was:

```
PS D:\> cd "d:\" ; if ($?) { g++ "Test  1.cpp" -o "Test  1" } ; if ($?) { "./Test  1" }
./Test
```

The "cd" command and the "g++" command seemed to work but the part which actually executes the program to be malfunctioning. It interpreted the double quoted file name as a string and just displayed it as it is instead of running it. I searched on the internet on a solution to running .exe files with spaces in the name but couldn't find any. I'm sorry if the topic is unrelated or its due to my incompetence as I'm very new to programming.

Comment: quote the path.

Comment: Your prompt says `PS`. Is that PowerShell? If so, that's not the same as `cmd`.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake. I corrected it.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I'm sorry I did not understand. Could you please elaborate.